# How do I import and activate a SAN SSL certificate in IIS?

Tags: ssl, iis, openssl, ssl-certificate, subject-alternative-name

the scenario is the following:

I created a selfsigned SAN certificate bundling different intranet-domains, hosted on different machines and OS. The certificate is working as expected when being used by apache-services on CentOS and nginx-services on Docker, but when I tried using the same certificate for a domain being hosted on a Microsoft IIS, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

From my understanding, even a faulty certificate should not trigger a 502 error, should it? And seeing as all other domains on different scenarios work just fine, I presume I did something wrong.

So this is my process for creating and exporting the certificate to IIS:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout cert.key -out cert-crt -days 365 -config san.cnf
```

san.cnf is a config describing the different domains I need etc. After creating certificate and private key, I export a .pfx version of the certificate with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs 12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in cert.crt
```

I then import said .pfx file to IIS using the import function in the server certificate feature menu and configure the https:// binding of the domain to use this certificate. After restarting the webservice, I get 502 Bad gateway errors when trying to access the page.

Is there anything I am missing?
Thx in advance for any hints, I suspect it's plain stupidity on my part once again :D

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of web service did you create? For the WCF service, please enable HTTP activation in the Window features.
[image]
For the usage of the `SAN` certificate, we need to configure a binding for every domain name accordingly in the web site binding module.
Like the below figure.
[image]
Particularly, there is no need to tick the below option since this kind of certificate support Subject Alternative Name. These bindings use the same certificate.
[image]
At last, I suggest you bind another certificate to verify whether the certificate caused this issue.
Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: the webservice I am hosting on the IIS in question is DokuWiki, I will try your suggestions when I am at work the next time. Thank you